# Laravel : check if a list of models already exist and update them with different values

Tags: php, excel, laravel

in a laravel application i use a package to import excel files to a model table.
some rows in the excel file are new, others are an update of existing models in the database. is there any way to insert the new records and update the existing records (with different values) using eloquent or the query builder.

Comment: OK.. Post Your Code.. Let's see what you have tried..

Comment: use `updateOrCreate` method, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell you will need to pick identifiers in your spreadsheet that uniquely distinguish each row. Email for example or an ID. With those you can then query the DB to see if a given record already exists and based on that create or update.

Laravel makes this relatively easy with Eloquent's `save()` method which you can call against a given instantiation of a model.

`save()` will, assuming you set your model up correctly, decide whether a row already exists and needs updated or if it doesn't and needs created.

See here for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: in each file that i will import, it will be more than 1000 rows , have i to use save for each row ?

Comment: yes, you would simply loop over each row in the excel file, instantiate the corresponding model with the new data and call `save()` on it